# Chrome extension fails when detecting iframes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

Basically what i am trying to do is to detect number of frames which are contained within the G+ home page, and off course i do use a content script

**The Js file for the extension:**

```
var myIframes;
window.addEventListener('load'
,function()
{
    //If the window location matches the G+ home page
    //Log number of frames contained within it
    if(window.location.href.match("https://plus.google.com/u/0/"))
    {
        console.log('G+ loaded');

        myIframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
        console.log(myIframes.length);
    }
}
,false);
```

**The o/p log of executing this code is:**

> > G+ loaded
> >
> > 2

Now comes the strange part, when i  try to access the *myIframes* variables length from within the inspector console, i got **8** frames.

So my question is **"How come !."**, shouldn't the *myIframes* variables stay as it was when it first get evaluated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')` returns a nodeList.

nodeLists are [**live**](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#td-live), they will update when the DOM changes.